# Correct way to install Typescript in React/Next.js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Next.js application that I want to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. This application uses Typescript.

I would like to know if Typescript needs to be installed in the dependencies or `devDependencies` section, as after Googling a lot I found conflicting information. These are the packages I have in dev:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.4",
    "@types/node": "18.11.17",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "eslint": "8.30.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.4"
  }
```

Is it correct to keep those packages in "`devDependencies`"? I also have some other packages that I am not sure of, like:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
"bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
```

Can someone give a hint? Ofcourse I want to deploy a built version of the app.

Answer (score 2):

`dependencies` are packages that are required for your app to run.
`devDependencies` are packages that have no use in production but that you use for development.

So, to retain your example, Typescript, ESlint, Jest are devDependencies; They are not called by your app after you've built it for production.

Conversely Bootstrap, FontAwsome etc., are dependencies; they are consumed by your app in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply consider `dependencies` equivalent to `something necessary during running` and `devDependencies` equivalent to `something necessary during developing`.

According to the typescript official site:

> TypeScript code converts to JavaScript

That means: until you are working with a project built on typescript abilities (like ts-compiler or something), or you should always install typescript as `devDependencies` like the typescript official site recommended.

There is a feature I use to judge if a library `dependencies` or `devDependencies`: **POSSIBLE RUNTIME CODES**.

For example: bootstrap you mentioned up there includes `styles` `components` `utilities` and several parts aside. When we use a bootstrap abilities like `validate forms`, there must be some runtime codes.

however, the safest way is to follow the official site guiding :)

Answer (score 0):

For those starting new projects, you can select Typescript in the installation instructions using `npx create-next-app`.

Here’s a video on [Next.js 13.4 installation](https://youtu.be/Pa0EYmqaux4).